# Dynamic CRm 2013-Service Calender add custom field to Activity Tooltip

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Currently the service calender shows the Activity status, Subject and Date fields when we hover on the service activity scheduled.

Is there any way we can add any other field?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: What field(s) do you want to display?

Answer (score 0):

On some projects, I have used a third party addon called group calendar (http://www.mscrm-addons.com/Products/AddonsforMSCRM2011/GroupCalendar/tabid/171/Default.aspx)

This is effectively a separate ASP.NET application which is linked to from the sitemap which gives you a much richer set of views.

It costs money, but does address some of the functional limitations of the service calendar, so may fit your use case.

I don't believe it is possible to do this easily using the native service calendar.